# How to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(\log (n))^2}{n^2}$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(\log (n))^2}{n^2}$$

I know that this series converges (proof by Answer Sheet). However I need to prove it using comparison, integration, ratio or other tests.

---

The integration test doesn't seem to help.

The ratio test seemed to shed light except that it requires further proofs that $\frac{log(n+1)}{log(n)} < 1$ etc which makes me think this is not the best approach.

I considered the fact that $\log(n) < \sqrt{n}$ but this just shows that it is less than a divergent series which doesn't help.

Suggestions?

Comment: You can bound $(log (n))^2$ by $n^\epsilon$ for n sufficiently large, and then just choose epsilon small enough so that $2-\epsilon >1$ and conclude convergence from a p-test.

Comment: @Merlinsbeard Don't you want $2-\epsilon < 1$?

Comment: You would want $2-\epsilon > 1$ because for the p-test to work, the power in the denominator needs to be $\textit{greater}$ that 1.

Comment: @Merlinsbeard Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: $$\ln(x)=\lim_{n\to0}\frac{x^n-1}{n}$$?

Comment: @SimpleArt What for?

Comment: @Did Thought it could help.  Helps us justify statements like $\log^2(n)=o(n^{1/2})$ like Bernard's answer suggests.

Comment: @SimpleArt Sorry but I am not following: how does the limit $(x^n-1)/n\to\ln x$ when $n\to0$ (your comment) helps to show the limit $(\log n)^2/n^{1/2}\to0$ when $n\to\infty$ (Bernard's answer)?

Comment: @Did It shows $\log(n)=o(n^0)$, and $o(n^0)<o(n^{1/4})$, as in Bernard's answer.

Comment: @SimpleArt "It shows $\log n=o(n^0)$" Sure about that? Wow. (Secondary mystery: whatever one thinks of the assertion that $\log n=o(n^0)$, how is the limit $(x^n-1)/n\to\ln x$ when $n\to\infty$ related to it?)

Comment: @Did Didn't I just say $\ln(x)=\lim_{n\to0}\frac{x^n-1}n=o(x^0)$?  It holds through calculus, the integral of $x^k$ when $k\to-1$, adjusted with the constant of integration so that at $x=1$, it is equal to $0$.

Comment: @SimpleArt So you really think that $(\log n)/n^0\to0$ when $n\to\infty$? Hmmm... What is $n^0$ already?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40116/discussion-between-simple-art-and-did).

Comment: I think you mean $\log n =o(n^\epsilon)$ for all $\epsilon >0$, or something like that. Taking $n^0$ ($=1$ makes no sense).

Comment: @SimpleArt No chat, thanks. "I would recommend you try graphing (x^n-1)/n for extremely small values of n to see for yourself.
By extremely small values of n, I would try n=+/- 0.0000001" Well... Be aware that you are just making a fool of yourself by posting such things. Time to come back to your senses?

Comment: @Did Well, did you try graphing it?  And if I'm making a fool of myself, that's ok, so long as I manage to learn from my mistakes.  :)

Comment: @SimpleArt "did you try graphing it?" No need to "graph it", the limit is clear. But, say, how does this graph/limit help in the present case? O wait... this is the same question from the start, to which you did not see fit to answer, isn't it? Fortunately, we now know that, whatever the way you planned to use this limit, your suggestion was based on the *interesting* conception that $\log n\ll1$. You will understand that those of us uneasy with the asymptotics $\log n\ll1$ would not follow the suggestion. (But, in the future, just try not to make everybody lose their time, thanks in advance.)

Comment: @Did Sorry, but I found it the easiest way to justify Bernard's answer.  I just took it too far.  :/

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I am just surprise about the length of the debate of this post here anyway see my answer below ? it use only comparison test

Comment: @SquirtleSquad you may have a look to the answer below using comparison test

Comment: @GuyFsone Just me being a youngin', still learning the ropes. [See also](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1795292).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is of course the homely old Integral Test:

$$ \ \int_1^{\infty} \ \ \frac{(\log x)^2}{x^2} \ \ dx  \ \ = \ \ \left[ - \ \frac{(\log x)^2 \ +  \ 2 \log x \ + \ 2 \ }{x} \right]_1^{\infty}  \ \ = \ \ 2 \ \ . $$

I'm not sure what the remark about the "integration test doesn't seem to help" is intended to mean: one must just be a bit patient with integration-by-parts and l'Hopital or some other limit technique.

In fact,  one finds that the result can be generalized to

$$ \ \int_1^{\infty}  \ \frac{(\log x)^p}{x^q} \ \ dx  \ \ $$

convergent for integers $ \ p \ \ge \ 1 \ $ and $ \ q \ \ge \ 2 \ $ .  We have   $$ \ \int_1^{\infty} \ \ \frac{(\log x)^p}{x^2 } \ \ dx  \ \ = \ \ p! \ \ , $$

[**EDIT:** This last result can be demonstrated by connecting the reduction formula,

$$ \ \int  \ \ \frac{(\log x)^p}{x^2 } \ \ dx  \ \ = \ \ -\frac{(\log x)^p}{x} \  \ + \ \ p \ \int  \ \ \frac{(\log x)^{p-1}}{x^2 } \ \ dx \ \ , $$

with our earlier expression for $ \ p \ = \ 2 \ $ . ]

and  $$   \frac{(\log x)^p}{x^2 } \ \ge \ \frac{(\log x)^p}{x^q }    $$

for $ \   q \ > \ 2 \ $ and $ \ x \ \ge \ 1 \ $ .  This establishes our convergence proposition for the improper integrals (by integral comparison), so

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(\log n)^p}{n^q} $$

converges for integers $ \ p \ \ge \ 0 \ $ and $ \ q \ \ge \ 2 \ $ .

Comment: Powerful answer! Tomorrow, when I have more time, I will try to understand everything fully, because they seem to be some really nice / interesting identities!

Comment: On thinking about this post a bit later one, it occurs to me I should say a little more on how the $ \ p! \ $ comes about.  The improper integral here  is in fact a transformed version of the one defining the gamma function.

Comment: The $ p!$ occurred to me as the nice results :)

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [Cauchy's condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)?

Remark : This test is usually useful to get rid of logarithms when trying to check if a series converges or diverges.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 5):

This is a *Bertrand's series*. You can easily prove convergence using asymptotic analysis.

Indeed, we have $\log^2n=_\infty o(n^{1/2})$, whence 
$$\frac{\log^2n}{n^2}=\frac{o(n^{1/2})}{n^2}=o\biggl(\frac1{n^{3/2}}\biggr).$$
As both are series with positive terms and the latter converges, the former does too.

Answer (score 0):

By comparison test we have $$\frac{n^{3/2}(\log (n))^2}{n^2}= \frac{(\log (n))^2}{n^{1/2}} =\left(\frac{\log (n)}{n^{1/4}}\right)^2=\left(4\frac{\log (n^{1/4})}{n^{1/4}}\right)^2\to 0$$ that is for n large enough we have

$$\frac{(\log (n))^2}{n^2}<\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$

the convergence follow by Riemann series. see more general here  [On convergence of Bertrand series $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}\ln^{\beta}(n)}$ where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2563446/on-convergence-of-bertrand-series-sum-limits-n-2-infty-frac1n-alpha)

Comment: The down voter here have serious mind trouble

Comment: I agree. Their behaviour disgusts me. +1 to compensate

Comment: @Math_QED I am totally surprise how did someone just vote this like. I decided to pôst this answer because of the serious lengthy comment this post.

Comment: @https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2643893
 i am facing similar trouble here.