# $\ln(x)$ and Big O notation

Tags: limits, notation, logarithms, asymptotics

I have tried to assert that $\ln(x)=O(x^0)$ a few times, but it seems fairly obvious that this statement should be false, and so I've been faced with some rightful speculation.

My reason is that

$$\ln(x)=\lim_{k\to0}\frac{x^k-1}{k}=O(x^0)?$$

But if not, then I ask

> What is the smallest value of $k$ for $\ln(x)=O(x^k)?$  A proof would be nice, and possibly some cleanuping if my notation is used incorrectly.

Comment: I couldn't figure out if there was a tag for O notation.  If there is one, please add it.

Comment: I've added the (asymptotics) tag.

Comment: $\ln(x)$ is not $O(1)$ because it diverges. However it is $O(x)$, so there's your answer. However, this is not strict; $\ln(x)$ is called a sub-polynomial function because its asymptotic behavior is strictly slower than any non-constant polynomial

Comment: $x^0=1$ so claiming something to be $O(x^0)$ is to claim that it's bounded by a constant, $\ln x$ clearly isn't.

Comment: @AlexG. Can I say $\ln(x)=\lim_{k\to0^+}O(x^k)?$

Comment: No, that doesn't make sense. If anything, that would be saying $\ln(x)$ is $O(1)$, which it isn't

Comment: @AlexG. But for $k>0$, $\ln(x)=O(x^k)$?

Comment: @AlexG. I've also tried looking up sub-polynomial function, but it turns up pretty much nothing.

Comment: 1....$x^0=1$.....2.Are you asking about the asymptotic behavior of $\ln x$ as $x\to 0$ or as $x\to \infty$?

Comment: @user254665 Both.  There is Clement's answer and another, $O(x^k)$ as $x\to\infty$ and $k\to0$.

Comment: For some context, see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1793655/. Let us hope that users on this page have more success getting the message through, than two users on the other page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first point is: when you use asymptotic notations, you *need* to specify *with regard to what point the asymptotics is taken.* Here, it looks like this is when $x\to 0^+$; note that this could have equally been $x\to\infty$, so specifying it is required.

Now, you have that for any **fixed** $\alpha > 0$,
$$
\ln x = O(x^{-\alpha})
$$
when $x\to 0^+$, since $\left\lvert x^\alpha \ln x\right\rvert\xrightarrow[x\to0^+]{} 0$. Yet, this does not "go to the limit": there is no minimum $\alpha\geq 0$ for which this holds.

---

**Parenthesis:** you have $\ln x  = x^{\frac{\ln\ln x}{\ln x}}$, so you could technically write $\ln x = \Theta(x^{\frac{\ln\ln x}{\ln x}})$... but note that this means "taking $\alpha = \alpha(x) = \frac{\ln\ln x}{\ln x}$."

Comment: What about $O(x^\alpha)$ as $x\to\infty$ and $\alpha\to0?$

Comment: @Clement For some context: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1793655/. Good luck... :-)

Comment: You can do the same sort of think when x tends to infinity. But if you want asymptotics with regard to TWO parameters at the same time, you have to start defining what you mean by the O () notation then.

Comment: @Did Oh. ${}{}{} $

Comment: @ClementC. "Oh", in Bachmann-Landau's sense, I guess...

Comment: @Did my comment for the O was for the OP. I am not sure i am (nor that he is) clear on taking the asymptotics according to two parameters at the same time, here.

Comment: @ClementC. That is ok, your answer was insightful nonetheless.  Can we compare them separately at least?

Comment: Well, for fixed x, when alpha goes to zero you get constant vs. constant. The log is a constant wrt alpha, and x^alpha goes to 1.

Comment: @Did also, just got the joke.

Answer (score 1):

For $r>0$ take $M>1$ such that $1/M<r.$ For $y>M$ we have $$0<\ln y=\int_1^y (1/z)\;dz= \int_1^M(1/z)\;dz+\int_M^y(1/z)\;dz=$$ $$=\ln M+\int_M^y(1/z)\;dz<\ln M+\int_M^y(1/M)\;dz=\ln M+(y-M)/M.$$  $$\text { So, }\quad 0<(\ln y)/y<(\ln M)/y+(1-M/y)/M.$$ Therefore  $$0\leq \sup_{x\geq y}\;(\ln x)/x\leq \sup_{x\geq y}(\;(\ln M)/x+(1-M/y)/M\;)=$$ $$=(\ln M)/y+(1-M/y)/M.$$ $$\text {Therefore, }\quad 0\leq \lim_{y\to \infty}\sup_{x\geq y}\;(\ln x)/x\leq$$ $$\leq \lim_{y\to \infty}\;(\ln M)/y+(1-M/y)/M=1/M<r.$$ Since $r$ can be as small as desired, we have therefore $\lim_{y\to \infty}(\ln y)/y=0.$

For positive $a,b$ we have $$(\ln y)^a/y^b=((\ln y)/y^{b/a})^a=(((a/b)\ln y^{b/a})/y^{b/a})^a.$$ Let $z=y^{b/a}.$ Then $z\to \infty$ as $y\to \infty$ and we have $$(\ln y)^b/y^a=((a/b)^a\cdot ((\ln z)/z))^a\to 0$$ as $y$ (and $z$) go to $\infty.$

In particular with $a=1$ and $b>0$ we have $\lim_{y\to \infty}(\ln y)/y^b=0.$ So as $y\to \infty$ we have $\ln y=O(y^b)$ for any $b>0. $

Actually we have $\ln y=o(y^b)$ as $y\to \infty$ for any $b>0$ because  $\lim_{y\to \infty}(\ln y)/y^b=0.$

For $0<y<1$and $y\to 0$ let $x=1/y.$ Then  $|\ln y|/y=x\ln x$ and use the above inequalities.

Comment: :/  I feel like you avoided the question on whether or not I can say $\ln y=\lim_{b\to0}O(y^b)$ as $y\to\infty$.  But thank you on the proofs.

Comment: I dk what is meant by $\lim_{b\to 0} O(y^b)$. It does not appear in your Q.

Comment: It is implied by the equations in my Q, for if not $\ln x=O(x^0)$, then at least my Q implies $\ln(x)=\lim_{k\to0}O(x^k)$

Comment: @SimpleArt The OP is rightfully asking you the meaning of the (stunning) assertion: $\ln x=\lim_{k\to0}O(x^k)$. Why not provide this meaning? (Personally I couldn't, but surely you have a precise idea in mind when you continue to write these horrors after several people mentioned they are problematic...)

Comment: @Did Probably because I am no longer sure how to put it in any meaningful or "correct" way, if one were to exist.

Comment: @SimpleArt But 28 minutes ago, you stated as a matter of fact that your question implies this statement... **Are you a troll?**

Comment: @Did One does not take math as seriously as I and be a troll.  I am a high school student who hasn't even taken Calculus, (and if you search hard, this statement has been repeated) to be honest, I just lack the experience you have.  I'm just... unsure of how to approach the community sometimes, and this is a question I'd like to have a solid and satisfactory answer on, that's all.

Comment: @SimpleArt Then repeating ad nauseam the absurd statement that $\ln x=\lim_{k\to0}O(x^k)$ is not the way to go. Listening to what people are explaining to you might be more fruitful.

Comment: @SimpleArt "Let us continue this discussion in chat." Are you kidding me? No thanks.

Comment: @Did Oops, my bad.  And don't worry, I don't plan on making that statement anymore.  At most I'll probably say $\ln(x)=O(x^k)$ for $k>0$

Comment: @Did http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1795502 A troll does not spend 3 hours on one question so that the OP understands it.  And I'm sorry, but I don't feel this is no longer comment appropriate.

Comment: My difficulty with your notation is that $O(x^k)$ is not a function or even a set of functions, but an abbreviation for a  condition.... $\ln x=O(x^k)$ as $x\to \infty$ for any $k>0,$  but  $\ln x$ is unbounded as $x\to \infty$.... And  $\ln y=O(y^{-k})$ as $y\to 0$ for any $k>0$ but $\ln y$ is unbounded as $y\to 0$.