# Computing $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{(\sin(x))^{n}}{1-\sin{(x)}}\,\mathrm{d}x} $

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

> $\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$I would like to compute the following limit,  $$\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{(\sin(x))^{n}}{1-\sin{(x)}}\,\d x} .$$

I am looking for a high school answer.

I tried writing $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{(\sin(x))^{n}}{1-\sin{(x)}}\,\d x = \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{ε \to \frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^ε{\frac{(\sin(x))^n}{1-\sin(x)}}\,\d x},$$

but it doesn't help me, since $1 - \sin(x) \leq 1, \forall x \in \left[0,  \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right]$.

Comment: You can write the integrand as $\sum\limits_{k=n}^{\infty}\sin^k x$, if that helps. Don't know if it does.

Comment: Is it an exercise? Did you copy the exercise correctly? If it is not an exercise, how you came up with it? The claim is wrong as you can see from the answers below so you cannot prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Your integral does event convergence, for each $n$ we have $$ \int_0^{\fracπ2}\frac{(\sin x)^n}{1-\sin x}=\infty$$

In fact [Since see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842978/proving-frac2-pi-x-le-sin-x-le-x-for-x-in-0-frac-pi-2?s=1|244.4553) $$\frac2πx≤\sin x≤x,~~~~~~\forall x \in \left[0, \displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$$ we have

$$\frac{(\frac2πx)^n}{1-\frac2πx}≤\frac{(\sin x)^n}{1-\sin x}≤\frac{x^n}{1-x}\implies \int_0^{\fracπ2}\frac{(\frac2πx)^n}{1-\frac2πx}dx≤\int_0^{\fracπ2}\frac{(\sin x)^n}{1-\sin x}≤\int_0^{\fracπ2}\frac{x^n}{1-x}dx$$
then let $u= \frac2πx$ the we get

$$\infty=\int_0^{1}\frac{x^n}{1-x}dx≤\int_0^{\fracπ2}\frac{(\sin x)^n}{1-\sin x}≤\int_0^{1}\frac{x^n}{1-x}dx+\int_1^{\fracπ2}\frac{x^n}{1-x}dx=\infty$$

Comment: Please provide a proof for the fact that $\int_0^1{\frac{x^n}{1-x}} \to \infty$, becuase I am pretty sure it tends to 0 as $n \to \infty$...

Comment: why a down vote ? may you care to explain?

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{1-x}dx} \neq \infty$

Comment: @C_M did you compute the integral before you apply the limit? or you are just doing the reverse way

Comment: @C_M for each n that is equals to infinity there is no reason to apply the limit

Comment: From my point of view, you did it the reverse way. By all means, prove me wrong, I want to see how you solve the integral.

Comment: @C_M I have solve it ? that integral is obviously infinity since the singularity is at x=1. then  at x= 1 we have $$\frac{x^n}{1-x}\sim  \frac{1}{1-x}$$ this is blatantly obvious I don't see how I can prove something obvious

Comment: You can switch the limit with the integral only if the integral converges uniformly. I want to see how you prove that it converges uniformly.

Comment: @C_M my friend where did I use the limit in my text? nowhere.   please read at least the first sentence I have added for you . for all n we have this $$\int_0^{\fracπ2}\frac{(\sin x)^n}{1-\sin x}=\infty$$ then why do you want to use the limit here ? it is non sense to use the limit there

Comment: My apologies, but I just don't see why. This is not "obvious". Open any graphing calculator, use every approximation for $\frac{\pi}{2}$, make $n \to \infty$ and you will see that integral doesn't diverge to $\infty$

Comment: @C_M I have added the last line why it is infinity if you dont get that one then I am sorry tooo. there is nothing I can do for you all details a re there

Comment: @C_M thanks for removing your down vote

Comment: You are right. Also, your idea to use $\frac{2}{\pi}x \leq \sin{x} \leq x$ helped me solve the problem from which I got the integral my question.

Comment: @C_M. that is indeed a powerfull inequality. you should keep it in mind

Answer (score 2):

The integral fails to converge for all $n$ as $1-\sin x \sim (\pi/2-x)^2$ near $\pi/2.$

Comment: All too easy.  (+1)

Comment: Near $\pi/2,$ I get $1 - \sin x \rightarrow 0,$ and $(1-x)^2 \rightarrow (1-\pi/2)^2$

Comment: @saulspatz That was a typo, thank you for the correction.

Comment: @C_M Each integral is infinite. The sequence is just $\infty,\infty, \infty,\dots$ There's nothing to do

Answer (score 0):

**just a hint**

Write the integral as
$$I_1+I_2=$$

$$\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}-\epsilon}+\int_{\frac {\pi}{2}-\epsilon}^\frac\pi 2$$
with
$$I_1\le \frac {(\cos (\epsilon))^n}{1-\cos (\epsilon) }$$ goes to zero.
and

$$I_2\le \epsilon \frac {1}{\cos (\epsilon)} $$

Comment: I am facing similar issue. but any way what is your point when give the upper bound. ? I dont think the integral converges at all

Comment: @GuyFsone I still cannot delete from mobile. thanks in advance.